# Mail validation angular laravel

Tags: angularjs, validation, laravel

I have a problem. With angular and laravel I can validate data, the problem is with email field, because laravel and angular use two different reg exp to validate it. I thought to add a custom reg exp in both sides to validate the field in the same. Is there a better solution?

EDIT

Angular validation not give me error when I omit dot

Comment: Just make your html input type as email

Answer (score 0):

you can use html5 input type email. it has a built in validation. and should be the same format as laravels

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html

but normally there should be no difference between laravel and angular email validation. can you maybe give an example where they two differ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
  <p ng-show="frmBoard.$submitted || frmBoard.email.$touched" class="has-error">
  <span class="help-block" ng-show="frmBoard.email.$error.email">
    Not valid email!
  </span>
```